# How many ways are there to distribute 12 distinguishable balls into 6 distinguishable bins so that 2 balls are placed in each bin?

Tags: probability

This is what I've done:
Number of ways = C(12,2) x C(10,2) x C(8,2) x C(6,2) x C(4,2) x C(2,2) x 6!

So basically what I'm trying to do over here is to pick 2 balls randomly for each of the bins. I multiplied in 6! cos there are 6 distinguishable bins.

The answer that I've obtained using the above method is wrong. I figured out that I'd have gotten the answer if I didn't include in 6! but I'm not too sure why is that so :/

I've came up with another method to solve the question that is :
Number of ways = 12!/ (2^6)

The above method gives me the correct answer but I just want to know what went wrong in my first method. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: About your first method: you first picked out $2$ balls for the *first* bin (let's say the bin with label $1$): $C(12,2)$ ways. Then you picked out $2$ balls for the *second* bin (the bin with label $2$): $C(10,2)$ ways. Et cetera. Multiplication with $6!$ afterwards should be left out. The fact that the bins are distinguishable is allready included.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks! :)